Deleting parts of a string across multiple variables
Trying to figure out this problem with some survey data. The responses are in multiple languages but always start with a number. Example: "1-Agree" or "1-Acceurdo." I am trying to isolate just the number so everything after the numerical correspondent gets deleted.
Simple enough, but where I'm getting tripped up is how to do it across a multitude of variables. Luckily, all variables of interest start with "pre" or "post" so I'm seeing if maybe there's a way to effectively loop through all these variables to isolate the number?
Additionally, there are certain questions that allow the respondent to select multiple values so it can't just be "delete everything after 1st character." One solution could be after to delimiter the data by comma?
Code for delimiting:
df$Pre3<-(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(df$Pre_3), ",", fixed = TRUE)))

Pre_3="1-Doctor, 2-Nurse, 6-Hospital"

would turn into
Pre3[,1]="1-Doctor" : Pre3[,2] ="2-Nurse" : Pre3[,3]= "6-Hospital"



Hi simone96, please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data (with dput()). It doesn't have to be your real data if it's confidential. It will greatly improve our ability to help if we can directly recreate the problem instead of having to spend time transcribing a screenshot.

Assuming you want to delete everything except the number, you need to use some basic RegEx:
library(stringr)
MyString <- "1-This is something, 2-this is something else"
Numbers <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", MyString)
Delim <- paste(str_split_1(Test, ""), collapse = ",")

The first expression says find anything that is not a number, and the second says to replace it with nothing. That should work unless some of the text answers have number characters.
Line three is in case you need to separate the numbers and add a delimiter.
If you need to transform your dataframe two options are:
df <- data.frame(Pre_3 = rep(MyString, 5)) # Create data frame
df$Pre_3 <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$Pre_3) 

library(dplyr)

df2 <- mutate(df, across(1:1, ~gsub("[^0-9]", "", .)))

The first will work for replacing one variable, or you could use dplyr across for multiple variables. Specify the columns to transform, and then a ~function, and the "." tells gsub what the current variable/column is.
Replace the 1:1 with the column range you need, or use something like c(1, 10:15, 20:22).

I think across() is a quick way to do it.
Example data
df <- data.frame(
  Pre_1 = c("1-Agree", "1-Acceurdo.", "2-Agree", "2-Acceurdo."),
  Pre_2 = c("2-Agree", "2-Acceurdo.", "3-Agree", "3-Acceurdo."),
  Post_3 = c("4-Agree", "4-Acceurdo.", "5-Agree", "5-Acceurdo."),
  Post_4 = c("5-Agree", "5-Acceurdo.", "6-Agree", "6-Acceurdo.")
)
df

> df
        Pre_1       Pre_2      Post_3      Post_4
1     1-Agree     2-Agree     4-Agree     5-Agree
2 1-Acceurdo. 2-Acceurdo. 4-Acceurdo. 5-Acceurdo.
3     2-Agree     3-Agree     5-Agree     6-Agree
4 2-Acceurdo. 3-Acceurdo. 5-Acceurdo. 6-Acceurdo.

Use parse_number() from readr package to get the first number and remove the rest. Also use across() from dplyr package to apply the same function to all columns picked up by starts_with():
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with(c("Pre", "Post")), parse_number))
df_new

> df_new           
  Pre_1 Pre_2 Post_3 Post_4
1     1     2      4      5
2     1     2      4      5
3     2     3      5      6
4     2     3      5      6
> 

If I misunderstood your question, a reproducible example with the expected results would be helpful for others to work out a solution.
